# How to define word boundry with chars like #:.[ in regex on javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I want to search this word: `'#foo'`

in this string:

```
first foo second #foo
```

so that **only the last '#foo' (with '#') will match**

I use this code and it causes two mistakes:

```
var mySearch ='#foo'
var regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + mySearch + '\\b', 'g');
```

1. searching `mySearch = 'foo'` will result a match to both "foo" (wrong! - should match only the first)
2. searching `mySearch = '#foo'` will result no hit at all (wrong - should match the second)

how to write it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var regexp = new RegExp('\b' + mySearch + '\b', 'g');
```

Comment: it won't work (I already tried it). when doing so the output of the regex itself is not as we want it to look like this '/\b#foo\b\/' but something strange with weird chars (I can't copy-paste it here). anyway - this regex '/\b#foo\b\/' will still cause the problem I stated in my question

Answer (score 0):

`\b` in regex is *boundary of word*. It will fail to match the boundary between a space  and a pound `#`.

So your `regexp` should just be

```
var regexp = new RegExp(mySearch + '\\b', 'g');
```

Comment: thanks, but this is half of the solution since if I search for "foo" it will match the "foo" in "#foo" and I don't want that...

Comment: @Alon If you want to match `foo` without `#foo`, the pattern should be `(^|[^#])foo`, which means `foo` should not follow a `#`.